# Debugging haskell in VS Code

Tags: haskell, visual-studio-code

I am trying to debug a simple Haskell application in VS Code with the phoityne-vscode plugin.
I managed to configure the plugin and run the application - I can see the breakpoints being hit.

The problem is cannot figure out how to interact with the running application. I have a line where I expect user input

```
do
  someValue <- getLine
```

Once the debugger reaches this line it stops and I cannot figure out how to pass arguments to the program. I would guess it is somewhere in the *Debug Console* but it looks like the prompt is only for driving the debugger.

I am sure I am missing something very simple - it's my first attempt at tempering with Haskell and I'm new to VS Code too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As described in repository - [You can't use `STD[IN|OUT]` methods](https://github.com/phoityne/hdx4vsc);
Something like `putStrLn` will be ignored, but `IN` methods (`getLine` for example) just will get stuck;

For functions without `STD[IN|OUT]` methods You can use `F10` - select function and send params (for example `[1,2,3]` for send list or `"str"` for send string):
[image]

With `F5` You can run previous configuration or configuration from `launch.json`:

- `mainArgs` - params, that You can get with [`getArgs`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/System-Environment.html#v:getArgs) (cmd params for your programm);
- `startupFunc` - name of the function that will be call first;
- `startupArgs` - params for that first function (for example `"startupArgs": "666"` will the same as `<F10> -> 666 -> <Enter>`)
- `stopOnEntry` - boolean param for enable\disable breakpoint at the start of the function;

Also, if I understood correctly, `F10` will rewrite `startupFunc` and `startupArgs`;

I'm really new in haskell so I'm confused a little bit when I can get value of constant in debug console, sometimes I have:

> [DAP][ERROR] error occurred while runStmt.
>   Variable not in scope: <...>

Also look like `where` and `let` blocks are ignored `:D`
Use `watch` panel for better understanding when You can use some constant:

[image]

If You want to debug input\output methods You can use `ghci` debug commands (`:h` - `Commands for debugging` block);

For example, You have a program:

```haskell
89| test :: IO ()
90| test = do
91|   a <- getLine
92|   b <- getLine
93|   putStrLn $ a ++ b
```

Use `:break 93` to add breakpoint at the 93'th line;
Then run your program in interpreter: `test`;
Enter values. Now You will stop at `putStrLn $ a ++ b` - if You type `a` or `b` in console - You'll get values of these constants;
Then `:step` for evaluate `++` and `:step` for `putStrLn`:

[image]

I hope it will be helpful for someone;